# Validation rule - should not contain the values

Tags: apex, validation-rule

AND (
NOT(Address = "P.O. Box","PO Box")

)

Validation rule should fire when address has these values, when I tried to save the rule got  Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic syntax issue. You are trying to use `=` operator with two values. May be you wanted to write this, assuming `Address` field is a `text` field, `AND(NOT(Address = "P.O. Box"), NOT(Address = "PO Box"))`

As **updated** if Address is a `address` type then check for their postal code values is `ISBLANK`

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_account_address.htm&type=5

Check more on how to use operators and fucntions here : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank You, still I got the error : Incorrect argument type for operator '='..
The rule should fire if address has P.O. Box or PO Box.

Comment: I have already written that assuming address is a `text` field. What is the field type of Address?

Comment: It's is a address type field

Comment: Ok, so if its Address type, then simply check for its postal code value like this, so if you are checking for Mailing Address then check for `(ISBLANK(MailingPostalCode))` or else if you are checking for Other address then check for `(ISBLANK(OtherPostalCode ))` or if both then add a `AND` condition.

Comment: AND(
 LEN(ShippingPostalCode > 1),
 NOT(
  CONTAINS("P.O. Box:Post Office Box",  ShippingPostalCode )
  )
  )
I have tried this way still got error : syntax error

Comment: What is `P.O. Box:Post Office Box` ?

Comment: Issue resolved. It's due to the extension on the chrome website, once it was turned off no issue